# Wait for event OR user abort in shell

Tags: shell, unix, dialog

I'm writing a shell (zsh) script that uses `dialog(1)` to draw a fancy text UI.

There is a place where I need to wait for one of the following to occur:

- an external event (I poll a shell function that normally returns false; I want to stop waiting once it returns true);
- the user pressing the "abort" button in dialog (with the dialog ideally showing how much is left until we time out);
- a timeout.

The timeout+polling combination is easy; however, I'm not getting anywhere with `dialog(1)`.

I can show a gauge that counts up as I wait for the timeout or the external event to occur, but the gauge dialog has no controls, there is no abort button.

Or I can show a pause dialog which has a countdown and a cancel button (with `--nook` there is no OK button), but if I start dialog like that, it'll keep running until the timeout is over or until the user presses cancel even if the external event occurs meanwhile.

I can start `dialog --pause` in the background, which would allow me to keep polling for the external event and kill `dialog` when the event occurs, but then it becomes difficult to catch the case where `dialog` exited.

One way around that would be to start `dialog` as a coprocess with `coproc` and keep checking whether the coprocess is still there, but that doesn't work because the coprocess gets suspended if it tries to write to the tty. (Actually, this would also be a problem when running `dialog` in the background.)

As a possible kludge, I could probably keep showing some `dialog` widget with a one-second timeout in a loop, but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kludgy solution would look like this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    dialog --timeout 1 --ok-label Abort --msgbox "$[100-i] seconds to time out" 0 0 && break
    poll_event && break
done
```